# binding value in array and returning the array dynamically in C

Tags: c, dynamic

I am using strtok_r from string.h to parse the line in a string and the token gives individual line. how can I bind this all lines in a array and return in the caller function.

```
    void call_strtok(char *str)
    {
              char *token, *remstr ;
            token = strtok_r(str,"\n",&remstr);
            // printf("token=%c",token[0]);
            while(token != NULL)
            {
                if(token[0] = ' ')
                {
                token = col_trim_whitespace(token);
                if(strcmp(token,"")==0)
                     {
                         token = strtok_r(NULL, "\n", &remstr);
                          continue;
                      }
                }
                printf("token=%s\n",token);
                 _syslog_data_t *data = create_new_syslog_data_t(token);
                token = strtok_r(NULL,"\n",&remstr);
            }
  }
int main()
{
  char str[] = " this \n is \n the \n test\n program";
  call_strtok(str);
  return 0;
}
```

I can have more lines in the string thus the array to be returned must be dynamic and thus be accessed in the caller main function.

Comment: you could use `malloc()`?

Comment: Careful, `if(token[0] = ' ')`  shouldn't it be `if(token[0] == ' ')`, `==`?

Answer (score 0):

Because at the start it is not known how many tokens you will read, you don't know the size of the array to allocate. Then you could create a linked list and append tokens to this list until done. Now you know the size of the array and can allocate it with malloc and place the tokens read in the array.

When constructing the list, allocate room for each token, i.e. `strlen(token)+1` and copy `token` to it.

You must inform the caller of the size of the array. There are two ways: as a parameter or by defining that the last array entry is NULL, indicating the end.